# How can I pass a body from stored procedure to a REST service?

Tags: sql, json, rest, post

I want to be able to POST a json message to a REST service. I am able to do a GET call by using examples from google-search

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
'http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT', 
    --Your Web Service Url (invoked)    'false'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

I have tried different variations of the following:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
DECLARE @hResult int
DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255) 
declare @Body as varchar(8000) = 
'{
    "Subsystem": 1,
    "Exception": "",
    "Message": "I have done what you asked",
    "Time": "2014-06-09T11:16:35",
    "Attribute": { "Number of attempts": "0" }
}' 

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post', 
    'https://thecorrecturl:446/api/handelse/', 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

declare @len int
set @len = len(@body)
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestBody', null, 'Body', @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

The ResponseText I get back is the omnious "{"Message":"An error has occurred."}"

Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this or just give the correct way to do it ;)

I have used the GET call to my url and got the correct handelse from the service.

Regards
Caroline

Comment: Did you notice that `false` all the way on the right? after the "your web service URL" comment. does that trigger the issue?

Comment: If I change from false to true I get a NULL response instead but still the same error on the server side (from the IIS log
POST /api/handelse/ - 446 - XXXXXXXXXXX 500 0 0 203)

Comment: have you tried running the calls from management studio to see what the error is?  just saw your edit - good thing you found the issue

Answer (score 20):

Caroline's solution:

A colleague of mine stumbled on the solution

Instead of using

```
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
```

we used

```
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
```

The final result that posted a handelse to our service looks like

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @Body as varchar(8000) = 
'{
    "Subsystem": 1,
    "Exception": "",
    "Message": "I have done what you asked",
    "Time": "2014-06-09T11:16:35",
    "Attribute": { "Number of attempts": "0" }
}'  

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC  sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post','https://thecorrecturl:446/api/handelse/', 'false'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Hope this helps someone else

Regards
Caroline

Answer (score 0):

Brian query works fine.
I you want to have API key add the following line

```
declare @apikey as nvarchar(32) = 'your api key';     
..
/*after content-type*/
exec sp_OAMethod @object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'ApiKey', @apikey
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian's answer is essentially what you asked for, although I would also add some debugging, resulting in something like this:

```
DECLARE @hResult INT;
DECLARE @source nvarchar(255), @desc nvarchar(255)
....
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @return OUTPUT
IF @hResult <> 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object, @source OUT, @desc OUT
    SELECT hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult),
           source = @source,
           description = @desc,
           FailPoint = 'ResponseText failed'
    goto destroy
    return
END
```

You can do this in each step of sp_OAMethod calls, so you know where it failed if it does.

However, please bear in mind sp_OAMethod 'responseText' has a limitation, it can't process an output larger than varchar(8000)

Also, since you mentioned you are working with JSON, the answer should be processed along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@return, '$.response') 
WITH (
    Item nvarchar(255) '$.item',
    Description nvarchar(255) '$.description',
    ...
)
```

With this you should be able to read the JSON response, and have each field as a column that you can later work with in a better manner.

Please note you probably have to set an additional 'Authorization' header for most APIs.